# How to get data from two endpoints in 1 component?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my not working version:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tokenType")) + " " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")),
        },
    };
    axios
        .get("/users", requestOptions)
        .get("/groups", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            setUsers(response.data);
            setRenderedUsers(response.data);
            setIsLoading(true);
        })
    .catch((err) => alert(err));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
      const responseOne = responses[0]
      const responseTwo = responses[1]
      const responesThree = responses[2]

      // use/access the results 

})).catch(errors => {
      // react on errors.

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) here.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tokenType")) + " " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")),
        },
    };
    Promise.all([
      axios.get("/users", requestOptions), 
      axios.get('/groups', requestOptions)
    ])
    .then(([usersResponse, groupsResponse]) => {
          setUsers(usersResponse);
          setRenderedUsers(groupsResponse);
          setIsLoading(true); // probably setLoading(false) here?
      })
    .catch((err) => alert(err));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to make multiple axios calls is like this:

```js
axios.all([
    axios.get('http://google.com'),
    axios.get('http://apple.com')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((googleRes, appleRes) => {
    // do something with both responses
  });
```

So your fixed example will be like this:

```js
axios.all([
    axios.get("/users", requestOptions)
    axios.get("/groups", requestOptions)
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((usersRes, groupsRes) => {
      setUsers(usersRes.data);
      setRenderedUsers(groupsRes.data); // Should it be users from groups? Just set it to what you need
      setIsLoading(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not chain Axios requests one to another, you need to make a seperate request per API resource you want to get, here is how you can get 2 requests in the same component

```
useEffect(() => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tokenType")) + " " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")),
        },
    };
    axios
        .get("/users", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            setUsers(response.data);
            setIsLoading(true);
        })
    .catch((err) => alert(err));

     axios
        .get("/groups", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            setRenderedUsers(response.data);
            setIsLoading(true);
        })
    .catch((err) => alert(err));
}, []);
```